Old B/W TV movie about a man growing up in a mental hospital
I'm looking for a movie about a doctor that has a practice and a mental institution. His nurse gets pregnant and she has the baby at the mental hospital and leaves it there because she is single. The doctor moves the baby into the common ward where the baby grows up around mentally incompetent patients.
The state takes over the practice and hires a new young doctor to go to the asylum to evaluate the patients there, where he finds this young boy who seems to be different than the others. The boy is quick to learn and soon begins to talk, which he didn't before.
The doctor takes the boy home, he and his young wife are having trouble creating a baby of their own, the boy grows up and learns of his situation, and one day leaves to find out who he is.

Are there any other things you remember that might help identification? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? Any descriptions of characters or places. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Your description sounds a lot like The Cider House Rules, however this movie is not B&W, nor was it made for TV.
This movie was released in 1999 and stars Tobey Maguire as the young man you describe. Michael Caine plays the older doctor that raises the boy.
from IMDB:

A compassionate young man, raised in an orphanage and trained to be a doctor there, decides to leave to see the world.

